# Android extract data from webpage

Tags: android, web-scraping, extract

I meet some difficulties to write my code.

I would like to use the data from a web page. for example the variable "TEST".

These data will be displayed in textview on my smartphone.

Here's the webpage code :

```
"<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;url=http://172.30.7.185\">\
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>\
<h1>TEST Web Server</h1>\
<a href=/><button type=\"button\">Reload</button></a>\
<script src=/s></script>\
<script>document.write(TEST)</script>\
</BODY></HTML>\
";
```

The variable "TEST" contains for example "42".

For the moment I can read the source code of the web page with my smartphone.
But I can not see how to extract the value (42) from the variable (TEST).

Comment: Not sure that i clearly understand what you what. Try to look at http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Your basically trying to parse the webpage itself?

It can be easily done using simple java code.

In this code you are trying to get the text between the  tags. You could use the function line.indexOf();

Basically create a String line; Put it in the whole html source tag and parse it.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use jsoup (http://jsoup.org/). It's a jQuery like parser in Java, very simple to use if you know CSS !